# Removing a directory in linux containing symlinks

Tags: linux, shell

I want to remove a nonempty directory in linux which has a directory structure inside it with bunch of symlinks. When I run

```
rm -rf /direcory
```

it removes not just all the symlinks and the directory, but also all the directories that those symlinks point to. Is there a command to just a directory which contains symlinks?

Comment: Which `rm` command are you using?  The standard one doesn't do that; it just removes the symlinks, not the things that the symlinks point at (unless the symlinks point at directories under the one you're removing anyway).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I checked the type it turns out it was a customized script, so nevermind :)

Comment: That's why, of all commands, you should not customize `rm`.  I hate it when 'protective' people try to customize it because they seldom get it right, and that makes it far more dangerous than the raw command which is at least predictable.

Answer (score 2):

Counter-example:

```
$ mkdir directory
$ cd directory
$ mkdir to-be-removed to-be-left-behind
$ cd to-be-left-behind
$ mkdir a b c
$ cd ../to-be-removed
$ ln -s ../to-be-left-behind/* .
$ cd ..
$ ls -lR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 jleffler  staff  170 Dec 17 17:25 to-be-left-behind
drwxr-xr-x  5 jleffler  staff  170 Dec 17 17:25 to-be-removed

./to-be-left-behind:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 a
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 b
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 c

./to-be-left-behind/a:

./to-be-left-behind/b:

./to-be-left-behind/c:

./to-be-removed:
total 24
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  22 Dec 17 17:25 a -> ../to-be-left-behind/a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  22 Dec 17 17:25 b -> ../to-be-left-behind/b
lrwxr-xr-x  1 jleffler  staff  22 Dec 17 17:25 c -> ../to-be-left-behind/c
$ rm -fr to-be-removed
$ ls -lR
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  5 jleffler  staff  170 Dec 17 17:25 to-be-left-behind

./to-be-left-behind:
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 a
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 b
drwxr-xr-x  2 jleffler  staff  68 Dec 17 17:25 c

./to-be-left-behind/a:

./to-be-left-behind/b:

./to-be-left-behind/c:
$
```

The symlinks are removed, but the directories they point at are not removed.

Therefore, there is something else at work in your example.  For example, if the symlinks pointed at files or directories under `to-be-removed`, then both the symlink and the targets would be removed, but only because the targets were in the line of fire anyway.